# PDF showing the special Spanish charters as "?"

Tags: java, xml, adobe

The adobe showing the special Spanish characters as "?". Do I need to fix the issue from adobe life cycle or from Java side? I forward XML to adobe life cycle with `UTF-8`. Do I need to encode it to something else like `ISO-8859-1`? What may be the problem here?
For example the word `Certificación` showing in the PDF as `Certificaci?n`.
in the console I see the words looks fine but once I call the adobe to get the PDF, I get the PDF with words like Certificaci?n.

I convert the object using

```
public static String obj2Xml(Class<?> className, Object obj)
        throws ServiceException {
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(className);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,
                Boolean.TRUE);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(obj, writer);
        return writer.getBuffer().toString();
    } catch (JAXBException jaxbException) {
        throw new ServiceException(jaxbException);
    }
}
```

i already did use ISO-8859-1 but i tested in HTML and was fine. my issue how can i encode the XML from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 as well as adobe life cycle. as i mentioned i pass XML to adobe and we use XSD where i changed as below

but still the console showing the XML with UTF-8

Comment: What Fonts are involved?

Comment: for example the word Certificación is showing in PDF as Certificaci?n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your problem with those special characters can indeed be fixed by changing your encoding to `ISO-8859-1`. (As you already mentioned in your question.)
See post https://stackoverflow.com/a/3688273/3178834


After 
`jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,Boolean.TRUE);`

you have to add:
`jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");`

 to enable the right encoding.

Plus you have to set your writer to the same encoding.
`OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "ISO-8859-1");`


Something like this...
Finally, that should encode your XML from to proper ISO-8859-1, instead of UTF-8.

Comment: thanks, i already did use ISO-8859-1 but i tested in HTML and was fine. my issue how can i encode the XML from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 as well as adobe life cycle. as i mentioned i pass XML to adobe and we use XSD where i changed as below    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://org.example.namespace/Notice/" targetNamespace="http://org.example.namespace/Notice/">

Comment: I edited my post. This way java will encode the XML to proper ISO-8859-1 right from the start. Hope it helps.

Comment: You can also use your `StringWriter` instead of the `OutputStreamWriter`. In this case you have to call `.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");` on the String returned by `obj2Xml`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, the console showing to me that the XML had been transformed with ISO standard but still the PDF replacing the special charactares with "?". do you thing some setting in adobe life cycle needs to be modified in order to solve this issue

Comment: Glad I could help. I would say the java-side and xml are both correct, so the issue has to be somewhere else. Maybe as you mentioned, changing some settings in adobe lifecycles could fix the problem. Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with lifecycles...

Comment: yes, it was from adobe life cycle. XWaveX,thanks a lot for your support :)